# A conceptual proof of Jacobi's product formula for $\Delta$ ?

Tags: modular-forms, reference-request

Let $\Delta$ be the unique normalized cusp form of weight 12 and level $1$. Then Jacobi's
wel-known formula states:
$$\Delta(z) = q \prod_{n=1}(1-q^n)^{24},$$
where $q=e^{2 i \pi z}$.

For a graduate class I am teaching on modular forms, I am looking for a conceptual proof of this formula, probably using the elliptic interpretation of $\Delta(z)$ as the discriminant of the Weierstrass equation $\mathbb C / \langle 1, z \rangle$. I believe that such a proof exists because Serre, in "cours d'arithmétique", mentions it, with a reference to a prewar paper in German by Hurwitz (Gesamm. Abh, III, no 62), that I was not able to find in my library. Serre himself gives a proof based on the quasi-modularity of the false Eisenstein series $E_2$, and I known another proof from Apostol's textbook, attributed to Siegel, and that uses a clever computation of residues
for the $\eta$ function. Both are interesting, but never can be qualified as conceptual
by modern standards.

> Do you know a proof of Jacobi's formula, or a reference (if possible modern and accessible)
>   for such a proof ?

Comment: It would be nice to mention the Hurwitz reference here (which journal and which year ?).

Comment: You're right. Done.

Comment: It's not "conceptual" in the sense you desire, but Weil's "Sur une formule classique" (Collected works vol III pp 198-200) uses the primordial version of "converse theorems" (in a self-contained fashion) to give a substantially believable proof.

Comment: Dear Paul, thanks for your answer. This is doubtlessly a conceptual proof, which for me is satisfying. But it is not something I can put in my course since I haven't time to discuss the converse theorems.



Comment: You may be aware of this already, but an anonymous blogger gave a nice argument using Hecke eigenvalues of the $E_2$ series: http://galoisrepresentations.wordpress.com/2012/10/26/jacobi-by-pure-thought/