# What is the relationship between the Leech lattice and Dedekind eta function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, lattices, theta-functions

Like this old question, [A conceptual proof of Jacobi's product formula for $\Delta$ ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108552/a-conceptual-proof-of-jacobis-product-formula-for-delta), I am asking again for a conceptual proof of Jacobi's miraculous product formula for $\Delta$ (the unique normalized cusp form of weight $12$ and level $1$), **but unlike the previous question, I am asking for a proof specifically from the point of the view of the Leech lattice**. For reference, that post contained the following 3 leads:

- a reference to a "prewar paper in German by Hurwitz (Gesamm. Abh, III, no 62)" that no one seems to have found/analyzed/discussed yet;
- Weil's "Sur une formule classique" (Collected works vol III pp 198-200) using a version of the "converse theorems";
- an argument from Frank Calegari (?) using "Hecke eigenvalues of the $E_2$ series": https://www.galoisrepresentations.com/2012/10/26/jacobi-by-pure-thought/

A similar MO thread [Where do the product expansions of modular forms come from?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129536/where-do-the-product-expansions-of-modular-forms-come-from) mentions also

- "products like $\Delta$ arise by exponentiation of a Howe theta lift (of which Shimura's correspondence is a special case), although the lift may need to be regularized."

One comment in the latter MO thread mentions connections to lattices. Remark 40 in [these notes of Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2021/02/02/246b-notes-3-elliptic-functions-and-modular-forms/#:%7E:text=Remark%2040,-The%20relationship%20between) also mentions that the product formula for $\Delta$ (now referring to [this normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function#Modular_discriminant)) is an "interpretation (after some additional effort)" of the relation $E_{12} - \frac{65520}{691}\Delta = \Theta_\Lambda$ where $\Theta_\Lambda(\tau):= \sum_{x\in \Lambda} e^{-i\pi \tau \|x\|^2}$ is the theta-function of the Leech lattice $\Lambda \subseteq \mathbb R^{24}$.

When I tried Googling this connection, I only came across https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493108/what-is-precisely-the-connection-between-the-leech-lattice-and-the-dedekind-eta, which links [some slides of John Baez](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/numbers/24.pdf), though I was not very satisfied with these answers (the post https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week125.html linked in the Credits provided some further insight).

**Question:** what exactly is the "some additional effort" needed to go between the relations $\Delta = (2\pi )^{12} \eta^{24}$ and $E_{12} - \frac{65520}{691}\Delta = \Theta_\Lambda$ alluded to above in [Tao's Remark 40](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2021/02/02/246b-notes-3-elliptic-functions-and-modular-forms/#:%7E:text=Remark%2040,-The%20relationship%20between)? I would really prefer an explanation which doesn't go into string theory/monstrous moonshine territory, if at all possible.

Comment: Given that the space of modular forms of weight $12$ is linearly generated by $E_4^3$ and $E_6^2$, and that $\Delta$, $E_{12}$, and $\Theta_\Lambda$ are in that space, there must be a linear relation between the three of them. Two Fourier coefficients are enough to determine the linear relation.

Comment: @Somos I'm aware. My question is about how to get from that relation to the eta function.

Answer (score 2):

Steve Carnahan in his answer to this question [Where do the product expansions of modular forms come from?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129536/where-do-the-product-expansions-of-modular-forms-come-from)
gives a conceptual explanation of the product form for $\Delta$, but it has nothing to do with the Leech lattice.

Comment: I am already aware of Steve Carnahan's answer, and in fact *quoted* it in the text of my post. Like you yourself said, your answer has nothing to do with the question I asked (in the title, and in the bold at the bottom of my post).

Comment: You asked for a conceptual explanation of the product formula and Carnahan provided one. Now you seem to insist on a conceptual explanation involving the Leech lattice but I see no reason why there should be one. You quoted Carnahan, but it wasn't clear to me you understood his explanation.

Comment: Very well, I will clarify my question to make it unambiguous that I am looking for an explanation involving the Leech lattice. It is discouraging to hear that you "see no reason why there should be one"; I assumed Tao got his remark from a widely-known source, but perhaps I will have to ask him directly what he meant.

Comment: *Scott* Carnahan